# Intelij 2019.1 update breaks JUnit tests

Tags: intellij-idea

After 2019.1 update broke all tests with error:

> no tests found for given includes xxxx.someThingTest

Comment: Did you change Java Compiler to something different than it was in previous version? Can you paste test code?

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no problem with test itself.... Worked before update.
JUnit tests testing spring application class methods, that's all.
This is pure settings problem.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Intelij somehow changed setting with update.

Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Runner > "Run tests using:"

Changed from "Gradle Test runner" to "Platform Test runner" and it worked.
I hope this is useful in some matter.

Comment: Very stupid to change the default test runner without any note. Wasted half an hour to find this solution. Should be marked as answer.

Comment: In IDEA 2019.2.3 it's called "Gradle (default)" and "IntelliJ IDEA". Pick the second and it will work.

Comment: @Mike actually you SHOULD mark your own answer. It will help others to find faster what they need. And thanks for sharing this. IDEA is great for many things but they do make it stupidly harder for others.

Comment: i could not see this option in 2019.2.4

Comment: Thanks. It is working for me : Run test using --> IntelliJ Idea

Comment: This option is not there on Android Studio Arctic Fox

Answer (score 12):

If you are using JUnit5 with Gradle, add below code to `build.gradle` file.

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I've got a hint from https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-gradle

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this `build.gradle` file for using Junit5

https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.4.0/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle/build.gradle

Comment: If after following the above solution if you still get the same error, it should be due to the Access modifiier of the method. Make sure your test method does not have `private` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem in 2019.2 for a newly developped class that was not detected. I strangely solved it by manually running "Build->Rebuild Project"

The workaround [with Runner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55417140/1484823) by Mike was not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to JDK 11.0.2 solved this for me.
Not sure if it is the real cause, though.

Answer (score 0):

When using JUnit 5, make sure that you use the interfaces provided by `org.junit.jupiter`

So for instance, you should annotate your tests with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` instead of `org.junit.Test`

For JUnit 4, and prior, use the interfaces provided by `org.junit`