# "No tests found for given includes" when running Gradle tests in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, junit5

I cannot run tests via Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA because of "No tests found for given includes" error.

How can I fix it?

GradleTests

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

public class GradleTests {
    @Test
    public void initTest() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.6.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Error:

```
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [GradleTests.initTest](filter.includeTestsMatching)
```

Some notes:

- Issue is reproduced with both JUnit 4 and 5
- IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3 (Community Edition), Build #IC-193.6494.35, built on February 11, 2020
- Test is in `src/test/java`
- changing runner like [Intelij 2019.1 update breaks JUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55417140/3520153) didn't help
- without `useJUnitPlatform()` result is the same

Comment: What's your Gradle version, and can you run the test from the command line?

Comment: And have you tried adding `testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0")`

Comment: @BenWatson thanks for help! I read more about JUnit5 last versions and find out that from 5.4.0 it has aggregated artifact "junit-jupiter" (it is more suitable for me) which included both api and engine. It seems that "engine" has been loaded from some other dependency in my main project.

Comment: So does it work with the aggregate artefact?

Comment: @johanneslink Yes, I can run my tests with aggregate artifact. I've added and accepted answer to this question.

Comment: @BenWatson I am using Junit 4.13.1, how to resolve this

Comment: https://www.positioniseverything.net/no-tests-found-for-given-includes/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks to [Ben Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729819/ben-watson) I've found solution. Since JUnit 5.4.0 there is aggregate artifact with both api and engine dependencies. So just adding one dependency to build.gradle resolved this issue.

```java
testCompile ('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.0')
```

Comment: Strangely, your solution didn't work for me and I have quite similar setup to yours. As a work-around I created manually a JUnit IntelliJ configuration ... but is not cool :/

Comment: I had to reopen the project. Intellij has loads of caching bugs that require stuff like this. Basically the gradle sync did not fix the project setup until it reopened the project.

Answer (score 91):

I had this error with a similar setup, but couldn't solve it with the previous answers. Resolved it by doing this.

1. File > Setting (Ctrl+Alt+S)
2. Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > gradle
3. Run Tests using: Intellij IDEA

All credit to: https://linked2ev.github.io/devsub/2019/09/30/Intellij-junit4-gradle-issue/.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me. I guess gradle plugin is broken

Comment: 3. Run tests using Intellij IDEA  -- and run the test -- your "problem" will still be there and the test will fail.  But Intellij will give you more "output".  In my case, the stupid test author (me) forgot to give the test a void return type.

Comment: Seems fresh versions of Android Studio don't have this parameter there anymore. Any idea?

Comment: This works for me, the default was using Gradle. However why using Gradle does not work? Anyone knows how to make it work using Gradle?

Comment: To make it work with using Gradle, the answer by Siamak works fine for me, just specify  useJUnitPlatform(), the gradle file was using useJunit()

Answer (score 19):

Gradle has no idea where to look for tests. Add this to your app build.gradle file root(Not inside android or dependencies closure):

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {     // This is for logging and can be removed.
        events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man - I had to switch out to use `useTestNG` in `build.gradle`

Comment: why isnt this a standard gradle feature?!

Answer (score 14):

/app/build.gradle

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
      useJUnitPlatform()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

In my case, **I had the wrong import**.

I needed `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;` instead of `import org.junit.Test;`

Answer (score 2):

Another cause of this behaviour when using IntelliJ to edit a Kotlin project is the folders used for the tests, Java classes need to be in a subfolder of java and Kotlin classes in a subfolder of kotlin.

Here's an example of a mini-project I created which demonstrates the folder structure https://github.com/znsio/AutomatedTestingWithKotlin/tree/main/src/test

I found the explanation which is quoted below together with the link to the source:

"*My problem was in single path to kotlin and java tests. So kotlin tests are in `root/src/test/kotlin/package` and they are running fine with `gradle :cleanTest :test` and java tests must be in `root/src/test/java/package`. Otherwise neither `compileTestKotlin` nor `compileTestJava` will not find java tests to compile.*"
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/not-able-to-run-unit-tests-on-kotlin-multiplatform-project/15779/7

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is case sensitive in choosing its selector. [See here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/testing-base/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/testing/filter/TestSelectionMatcher.java#L152) You may need to change "GradleTests" to "gradleTests"

Answer (score 1):

I've got an Error: No tests found for given includes: ... (filter.includeTestsMatching).

After I checked JUnit dependency I discovered junit-4.13.1 version.

Fixed with replacing this dependency to org.junit.jupiter.api-5.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the test method is granted public access.

Answer (score 0):

After going through all configurations and finding nothing, a simple gradle clean fixed this very persistent issue for me, and i could keep using "run tests with gradle".

```
./gradlew :domain:test --tests "..."


> Task :domain:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':domain:test'.

> No tests found for given includes: ...

./gradlew clean
./gradlew :domain:test --tests "..."


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the filename that contained the test class did not match the class name. So I had `AppRepositoryTest.kt` with `FetchDataUseCaseTest` test  class inside. Apparently Junit 4 does not like that, so once I made both names the same it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally put a .java test file into a kotlin folder and get this same error.  Once I moved the file from src/test/kotlin to src/test/java folder the error went away.  Doh!